# Updating the value in existing JSON data by key in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have JSON data and want to update the value by key.

JSON:

```
{
 "language":"en",
 "education":[
                {
                   "unit":"e1",
                   "language":"en"
                 }
              ],
 "membership":[
                {
                  "uei":"21",
                  "Uifed":"failed"
                }
              ]
}
```

I want to change the value of `uifed` from "failed" to "success".

**What have I done?**

```
$json = '{"language":"en","education":[{"unit":"e1","language":"en"}],"membership":[{"uei":"21","Uifed":"failed"}]}';
$arrayData = json_decode($json, true);
$replacementData = array('Uifed' => 'success');
$newArrayData = array_replace_recursive($arrayData, $replacementData);

echo var_dump($newArrayData);
```

**Result:**

`NULL`

How can I do that?

Comment: Iterate over `arrayData['memebership']` and replace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not how [`array_replace_recursive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive) works; the replacement arrays need to have the same structure as the one you are replacing into. For your sample data, this will work:

```
$json = '{"language":"en","education":[{"unit":"e1","language":"en"}],"membership":[{"uei":"21","Uifed":"failed"}]}';
$arrayData = json_decode($json, true);
$replacementData = array('membership' => array(array('Uifed' => 'success')));
$newArrayData = array_replace_recursive($arrayData, $replacementData);

print_r($newArrayData);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [language] => en
    [education] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [unit] => e1
                    [language] => en
                )
        )
    [membership] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [uei] => 21
                    [Uifed] => success
                )
        )

)
```

[`array_walk_recursive`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) can be used to do what you want:

```
$replacementData = array('Uifed' => 'success');
array_walk_recursive($arrayData, function (&$value, $key) use ($replacementData) {
    $value = $replacementData[$key] ?? $value;
});

print_r($arrayData);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [language] => en
    [education] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [unit] => e1
                    [language] => en
                )
        )
    [membership] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [uei] => 21
                    [Uifed] => success
                )
        )
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/ZCXUq)

Comment: Thank you, Nick! Byw, Greetings from Turkey to Australia :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple example with `foreach` and passing values **by reference**:

```
$json = '{"language":"en","education":[{"unit":"e1","language":"en"}],"membership":[{"uei":"21","Uifed":"failed"}]}';
$arrayData = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($arrayData['membership'] as &$membership) {
    if ('failed' === $membership['Uifed']) {
        $membership['Uifed'] = 'success';
    }
}
print_r($arrayData);
```

[Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/QluPF).